# How to put a geom_sf produced map on top of a ggmap produced raster

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, ggmap, r-sf

I tried the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(sf)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))
str(nc)

 Classes ‘sf’ and 'data.frame':  100 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ AREA     : num  0.114 0.061 0.143 0.07 0.153 0.097 0.062 0.091 0.118 0.124 ...
 $ PERIMETER: num  1.44 1.23 1.63 2.97 2.21 ...
 $ CNTY_    : num  1825 1827 1828 1831 1832 ...
 $ CNTY_ID  : num  1825 1827 1828 1831 1832 ...
 $ NAME     : Factor w/ 100 levels "Alamance","Alexander",..: 5 3 86 27 66 46 15 37 93 85 ...
 $ FIPS     : Factor w/ 100 levels "37001","37003",..: 5 3 86 27 66 46 15 37 93 85 ...
 $ FIPSNO   : num  37009 37005 37171 37053 37131 ...
 $ CRESS_ID : int  5 3 86 27 66 46 15 37 93 85 ...
 $ BIR74    : num  1091 487 3188 508 1421 ...
 $ SID74    : num  1 0 5 1 9 7 0 0 4 1 ...
 $ NWBIR74  : num  10 10 208 123 1066 ...
 $ BIR79    : num  1364 542 3616 830 1606 ...
 $ SID79    : num  0 3 6 2 3 5 2 2 2 5 ...
 $ NWBIR79  : num  19 12 260 145 1197 ...
 $ geometry :sfc_MULTIPOLYGON of length 100; first list element: List of 1
 ..$ :List of 1
 .. ..$ : num [1:27, 1:2] -81.5 -81.5 -81.6 -81.6 -81.7 ...
   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "XY" "MULTIPOLYGON" "sfg"
   - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
   - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "AREA" "PERIMETER" "CNTY_" "CNTY_ID" ...

map <- get_map("north carolina", maptype = "satellite", zoom = 6, source = "google")
a <- unlist(attr(map,"bb")[1, ])
bb <- st_bbox(nc)
ggplot() + 
  annotation_raster(map, xmin = a[2], xmax = a[4], ymin = a[1], ymax = a[3]) + 
  xlim(c(bb[1], bb[3])) + ylim(c(bb[2], bb[4])) + 
  geom_sf(data = nc, aes(fill = AREA))
```

The two layers do not overlap properly; I tried changing projection with `coord_sf()` but I did not have success.

any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: Can you post the result of `str(nc)` (edit your question)?

Answer (score 52):

I've struggled with this myself, and with the help of [this post](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/16660_7d1ab1b355344578bbacb0747fd485c8.html) I've come up with a solution.  The bounding box of the ggmap object is in WGS84 (EPSG:4326), but the actual raster is in EPSG:3857. You have to hack the bounding box of the ggmap object to be in the same CRS as the underlying data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.2, GDAL 2.3.0, proj.4 5.1.0

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)

# Transform nc to EPSG 3857 (Pseudo-Mercator, what Google uses)
nc_3857 <- st_transform(nc, 3857)

map <- get_map("north carolina", maptype = "satellite", zoom = 6, source = "google")

# Define a function to fix the bbox to be in EPSG:3857
ggmap_bbox <- function(map) {
  if (!inherits(map, "ggmap")) stop("map must be a ggmap object")
  # Extract the bounding box (in lat/lon) from the ggmap to a numeric vector, 
  # and set the names to what sf::st_bbox expects:
  map_bbox <- setNames(unlist(attr(map, "bb")), 
                       c("ymin", "xmin", "ymax", "xmax"))

  # Coonvert the bbox to an sf polygon, transform it to 3857, 
  # and convert back to a bbox (convoluted, but it works)
  bbox_3857 <- st_bbox(st_transform(st_as_sfc(st_bbox(map_bbox, crs = 4326)), 3857))

  # Overwrite the bbox of the ggmap object with the transformed coordinates 
  attr(map, "bb")$ll.lat <- bbox_3857["ymin"]
  attr(map, "bb")$ll.lon <- bbox_3857["xmin"]
  attr(map, "bb")$ur.lat <- bbox_3857["ymax"]
  attr(map, "bb")$ur.lon <- bbox_3857["xmax"]
  map
}

# Use the function:
map <- ggmap_bbox(map)

ggmap(map) + 
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(3857)) + # force the ggplot2 map to be in 3857
  geom_sf(data = nc_3857, aes(fill = AREA), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly to align my polygons to a google base map. Now I am unable to use ggplot2::annotate() or ggimage::geom_image() on the plot. Do you have any thoughts on how to label or add custom symbols after using your ggmap_bbox function?

Comment: I have the same problem. geom_sf_label doesnt work with this solution.

Comment: If your CRS does match already from ggmap basemap and your sf object, the key edit to make them work together from above is to use `, inherit.aes = FALSE)` in the geom_sf() call.

Comment: Very well done figuring out this hack. But frack me what a joke that it's required. Basically this mapping workflow is totally unsuited to teaching students..

Comment: I'm having trouble when crossing the dateline, st_transform is getting confused and giving a bounding box xmin = -19305843 ymin = -6594528  xmax = 17638313  ymax = -3463667

Answer (score 18):

You can use the plotting method from the `sf` package to do this.  You'll need to specify the coordinate reference system, which we will need to assume (and it looks like correctly so) is 3857.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(sf)

nc_shp <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))
nc_map <- get_map("north carolina", maptype = "satellite", zoom = 6, source = "google")

st_crs(nc_map)
# Coordinate Reference System: NA

# assume the coordinate refence system is 3857
plot(st_transform(nc_shp, crs = 3857)[1], bgMap = nc_map)
```

[image]

Comment: Shame that transparency is unavailable..

Answer (score 0):

All solutions are great, but let me add another option that worked for me.

**Use case: overlay Tigris roads into a ggmap**

1. get the roads and boundaries (US roads and State of OH):

   `US_roads <- primary_roads(); class(US_roads); OH_counties<-counties(state = "OH",year = 2018)`
2. Union counties to create a big geometry with the OH boundaries:

   `OH_poly <- st_union(OH_counties); plot(OH_poly)`
3. Intersect roads within OH

   `OH_roads<-st_intersection(US_roads,OH_poly); plot(OH_roads$geometry)`
4. convert from SF to SP for ggmap using an auxiliary function for retrieving the geometry of interest (e.g., Line or polygon):

   types <- vapply(sf::st_geometry(OH_roads), function(x) {
   class(x)[2]
   }, "")

   OH_roads2 <- OH_roads[ grepl("*LINE", types), ]

OH_roads3<-as(OH_roads2, "Spatial")

```
OH_roads3@data$id <- OH_roads3@data$LINEARID
OH_roads4 <- fortify(OH_roads3, region='LINEARID')
```

5. Plot the results:

   `get_stamenmap(bbox, zoom = 10, maptype ="toner") %>% ggmap() + geom_path(data=OH_roads4, aes(long, lat,group = id),alpha=1,size=1,color="#c280e9",lineend = "round")`

[image: final result]