# Plotting static base map underneath a sf object

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, ggmap, r-sf

I'm trying to plot a static base map underneath my `sf` object (for print). When using `ggmap` I first get a lot of errors, then I can't seem to figure out how to chain the base map to my `ggplot2` object with a `geom_sf`.

```
library(sf)
# devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap) 

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc_map <- get_map(location = "North Carolina, NC", zoom = 7)

ggmap(nc_map)

nc_centers <- st_centroid(nc)

nc_centers %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(color = SID79, size = BIR74),
          show.legend = "point") +
  coord_sf(datum = NA) +
  theme_minimal()
```

I also rather use the `source = "osm"` as style but those will always return `'400 Bad Request'`.

Is there maybe another good package for base maps?

Comment: `leaflet` is a good package imo - don't know though if you'll be able to complete your task with it.

Comment: `leaflet` for interactive maps right? I'm looking for static print solutions.

Comment: You can use `mapview::mapshot` to save leaflet maps as a static file (jpeg, png etc.). Maybe that suits your needs

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might consider reprojecting your data but the following code seems to work for me.
See [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/336) for an explanation about why you need `inherit.aes = FALSE` and see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47840144/2417437) for an alternative solution with base plots.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.5.1, GDAL 2.1.3, proj.4 4.9.2
# devtools::install_github("r-lib/rlang")
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap) 

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
#> Reading layer `nc' from data source `/home/gilles/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/sf/shape/nc.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> epsg (SRID):    4267
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs
nc_map <- get_map(location = "North Carolina, NC", zoom = 7)
#> Map from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=North+Carolina,+NC&zoom=7&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&language=en-EN&sensor=false
#> Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=North%20Carolina,%20NC&sensor=false
nc_centers <- st_centroid(nc)
#> Warning in st_centroid.sfc(st_geometry(x), of_largest_polygon =
#> of_largest_polygon): st_centroid does not give correct centroids for
#> longitude/latitude data

ggmap(nc_map) +
    geom_sf(data = nc_centers, 
            aes(color = SID79, size = BIR74),
            show.legend = "point", inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    coord_sf(datum = NA) +
    theme_minimal()
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: @GillesThanks for the excellent solution. Could you please add text annotation too? I have tried  geom_sf_label () but it seems to fail with this solution.

Answer (score 13):

I've been working on a [package](https://github.com/Chrisjb/basemapR) recently which someone may find useful. The ggmap answer now require an API key for use with google maps which adds an extra bit of faff.

`basemapR` also allows you a bit more flexibility in setting the extents for the basemap by using a bounding box.

```r
#devtools::install_github('Chrisjb/basemapR')
library(basemapR)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)


nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

nc_centers <- st_centroid(nc)

# create bbox from our nc layer and expand it to include more area above/below
bbox <- expand_bbox(st_bbox(nc_centers), X = 0, Y = 150000)

ggplot() +
  base_map(bbox, increase_zoom = 2, basemap = 'google-terrain') +
  geom_sf(data = nc_centers, 
          aes(color = SID79, size = BIR74),
          show.legend = "point", inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA,
           xlim = c(bbox['xmin'], bbox['xmax']),
           ylim = c(bbox['ymin'], bbox['ymax'])) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(caption = 'map data \uA9 2020 Google')
```

Remember to cite google maps in the caption or elsewhere in the map

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the package `ggspatial` which provides the "map tile" annotation layer.

```
ggplot(nc_centers) +
    annotation_map_tile(zoom = 7) +
    geom_sf(aes(color = SID79, size = BIR74),
            show.legend = "point", inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    coord_sf(datum = NA) +
    theme_minimal()
```