# Cannot plot sf layer on top of ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap, r-sf

Subject of some previous questions - e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626233/plotting-static-base-map-underneath-a-sf-object).  I cannot get the sf layer to render over the ggmap layer.

```
require(ggmap)
require(raster)
require(sf)

target_bbox <- c(left = -0.65, bottom = 51.2, right = 0.45, top = 51.8)
map = get_stamenmap(target_bbox, zoom = 9, maptype = 'toner-2010')

# can test this with: ggmap(map)

e = extent(list(x = c(-0.65, 0.45), y = c(51.2, 51.8)))
r = raster(volcano)
crs(r) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
p = raster::rasterToPolygons(r)
sf = st_as_sf(p) %>% st_transform(3857)

# test with: ggplot() + geom_sf(data = sf, aes(fill = layer), col = NA)

ggmap(map) + 
   geom_sf(data = sf, aes(fill = layer), col = NA, alpha = 0.4, inherit.aes = FALSE)
Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
```

[image]

Coordinate system clash but no errors, yet no layer is visible.  Any suggestions much appreciated.

[This github solution](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/160#issuecomment-397055208) - extracting the bounding box from the ggmap object with custom function `ggmap_bbox()` - only succeeds in adding another warning to that above:

```
Warning message:
In st_is_longlat(x) :
  bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to plot the `sf` volcano object over London, but you've defined it to be at lon/lat 0,0. Other than that, your call to `ggmap` and then `geom_sf` works fine. The problem was just that the sf object wasn't in the bounding box of the ggmap.

I had to change it to a 'Spatial' object to move it using `maptools::elide`, and then back to an 'sf' object as I couldn't find an easy way to shift sf polygons.  The shift is an eyeball approximation.

```
sf_moved <- sf %>% 
  st_transform(3857) %>% # <- may be unnecessary
  as('Spatial') %>% 
  maptools::elide(.,shift = c(-80000, 6650000)) %>% 
  as('sf') %>% 
  st_set_crs(3857) %>% 
  st_transform(4326) 

ggmap(map) + 
  geom_sf(data = sf_moved, inherit.aes = FALSE, 
          col = NA, aes(fill = layer), alpha = .4) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh dear. Rookie error - I forgot to assign the extent to the raster object `extent(r) = e`

Comment: Happens to everyone. Assigning the extent would've been much easier than my method!