# Ggmap Integer Values on Map

Tags: r, mapping, ggmap

I have a table summarising a balance for 15 different zipcodes, it has latitude and longitude. 4 columns in total: zipcode, balance (integer), latitude, and longitude.

Here it is:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgacZ.png)

Latitude and longitude were mapped from the main USA zipcodes database.

I want to reflect the balance of each zip code on the map, but it is not showing it.

Here is the code:

```
ggmap(map) + geom_point(data = eigpm_sp_summ2, aes(lat, lng,
                         size=mean_b)) +
  scale_color_gradient(low="black", high="blue")
```

Here is the map it is showing me:

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8LUX.png)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting static base map underneath a sf object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626233/plotting-static-base-map-underneath-a-sf-object)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a geom_sf layer to your code

```
ggmap(map) + geom_point(data = eigpm_sp_summ2, aes(lat, lng,
                         size=mean_b)) +
  geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = zip)) + 
  scale_color_gradient(low="black", high="blue")
```

Comment: Thanks @abdullah-faqih is still giing tis error _Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
Error in `geom_sf()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 5th layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'zip_code' not found_
Any ideas?