# R - Add Tigris SF Shapefile to ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap, r-sf, tigris, tidycensus

I am trying to add `shapefiles` on top of a `ggmap` object. Specifically, I would like to use `Simple Feature` (SF) `shapefiles` downloaded from the `R` package `Tigris`. I have tried to overlay these on `Stamen` and Google Maps from `ggmap`.

Packages used:

```
library(tigris)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)
library(sf)
```

First download `shapefiles` from the `Tigris` package. I am using county shapes for the states of Texas. I am specifically downloading these as an SF object (opposed to an SP object).

```
shp_tx <- tigris::counties(cb = TRUE, 
                           resolution = "20m", 
                           year = 2018,
                           class = 'sf', 
                           state = 'TX')
```

I then calculate a bounding box from this object, which is used to download a `stamen ggmap`.

```
my_bbox <- sf::st_bbox(shp_tx) %>% as.numeric()

my_map <- ggmap::get_stamenmap(bbox = my_bbox, 
                               maptype = 'toner-lite', 
                               zoom = 5)
```

Now when I try to overlay the counties `shapefile` on the `ggmap`, the borders do not properly align.

```
ggmap(my_map) +
  geom_sf(data = shp_tx, 
          aes(geometry = geometry),
          col = 'blue', 
          fill = 'lightblue', 
          alpha = 0.25, 
          inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

My understanding is that I need to re-project the `shp_tx` (SF) object into a `CRS` to match the my_map (`ggmap`) object.

I have tried multiple projections based on online posts, but none seem to work appropriately. Here are the ones I have tried:

```
shp_tx2 <- sf::st_transform(shp_tx, 
                            crs = 3857)

ggmap(my_map) +
  geom_sf(data = shp_tx2, 
          aes(geometry = geometry),
          col = 'blue', 
          fill = 'lightblue', 
          alpha = 0.25, 
          inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

And

```
shp_tx3 <- sf::st_transform(shp_tx, 
                            crs = 4326)

ggmap(my_map) +
  geom_sf(data = shp_tx2, 
          aes(geometry = geometry),
          col = 'blue', 
          fill = 'lightblue', 
          alpha = 0.25, 
          inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

I'm not sure if this transformation would be the same using a `Stamen Map` or a Google Map, but I have tried both and have had similar problems. I'm hoping the solution is as simple as transforming to correct CRS. Thanks.

Comment: I am having this exact issue currently! Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: No, I have not been able to find a good solution on this. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, I did some more digging after posting here and I actually found a solution. The github issue where the question was originally addressed https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/160#issuecomment-397055208, and a stackoverflow question which has this same solution, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749078/how-to-put-a-geom-sf-produced-map-on-top-of-a-ggmap-produced-raster/50844502#50844502. This worked for me, hopefully you can use it too.