# Plotting geom_sf over ggmap shape

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to plot a map shapefile on top of a map downloaded using the ggmap package. However, I get a cryptic error message and a not very useful traceback:

Code:

```
map <- get_stamenmap( bbox = c(left = 3, bottom = 48, right = 3.5, top = 49), zoom = 12, maptype = "terrain")

transformed_sample = st_transform(rpg_sf %>% filter(commune %in% smallcomslist), crs=4326)

ggmap(map) + geom_sf(data=transformed_sample, mapping=aes(fill=commune),lwd=0) 

#Here transformed_sample is an object of class "sf" containing some outlines of villages in the area given by bbox.

#This returns:

ggmap(map) + 
   geom_sf(data=transformed_sample, mapping=aes(fill=commune),lwd=0)
```

Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'lon' not found
> traceback()
> 10: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
> 9: lapply(aesthetics, eval_tidy, data = data, env = env)
> 8: f(..., self = self)
> 7: l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
> 6: f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
> 5: by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot))
> 4: ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
> 3: ggplot_build(x)
> 2: print.ggplot(x)
> 1: (function (x, ...)
> UseMethod("print"))(x)

I have no idea why a "lon" is expected. Any ideas?

Comment: This entry advises to use package `sf`s `plot`method for your `sf` object (= transformed_sample) and use its `bgMap` argument to set the stamen map in the background: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749078/how-to-put-a-geom-sf-produced-map-on-top-of-a-ggmap-produced-raster
However, this approach repeatedly crashed my R session, so take care ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Very late to this party, but after going down a rabbit hole of Coordinate Reference System changes, I solved a similar error by simply adding `inherit.aes = FALSE` in the `geom_sf()` layer. So your code would become

```
ggmap(map) + 
      geom_sf(data = transformed_sample, mapping = aes(fill=commune), lwd=0, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

As an FYI, if you use tidyverse quite a bit, I would advise against naming an object `map`. The package `purrr`, which gets loaded when you run `library(tidyverse)` also has a function `map()`.

Comment: My rabbit led me here, most appreciated. Definitely a case of better late than never.