# setting CRS for plotting with stamenmaps

Tags: r, r-sf, ggmap

I am trying to plot a simple polygon on a map to denote the area I am interested in.  To date, I have defined the polygon as and am able to plot it on it's own.

```
poly <- st_polygon(list(as.matrix(data.frame(lat = c(40, 40, 60, 60, 40),
                                             lon = c(-60, -40, -40, -60, -60))))) #EDIT: these are lat/lon coordinates
ggplot() + 
    geom_sf(data = poly,
    aes(geometry = geometry),
    col = "red)
```

However, I need to add a basemap so that I can show the placement of this polygon in relation to other spatial elements.

```
# Attempt #1: stamenmaps basemap

    grid_box <- c(left   = -70, 
                  right  = -30,
                  bottom = 35,
                  top    = 70)
    base <- get_stamenmap(grid_box, zoom = 6, maptype = "terrain-background", color = "color")
    ggmap(base) +
      geom_sf(data = poly, 
              aes(geometry = geometry),
              col = "red")

    Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
    Error in `geom_sf()`:
    ! Problem while computing aesthetics.
    ℹ Error occurred in the 4th layer.
    Caused by error in `FUN()`:
    ! object 'lon' not found
    Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The only approach I found for adding a crs to my polygon is below (st_transform & st_as_sf didn't work), but this dramatically changed the scale of the coordinates and still doesn't plot.

```
 # Attempt #2: new CRS

    poly <- st_polygon(list(as.matrix(data.frame(lon = c(-62, -43, -43, -62, -62),
                                                     lat = c(43, 43, 70, 70, 43))))) %>%
            st_sfc(crs = 3857)
    ggmap(base) +
      geom_sf(data = poly, 
              aes(geometry = geometry),
              col = "red")

Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
Error in `geom_sf()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 4th layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'lon' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

How can I get this polygon to plot over my basemaps?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are on the right track with `sf::st_sfc()` call in your second try. To make it work you have to think a bit what your coordinates mean?

In [EPSG:3857](https://epsg.io/3857) the coordinates are defined in meters. This seems not to be the case with your original columns named lat & long, which usually stand for latitude and longitude in degrees.

Should your coordinates be in degrees (which seems likely, though I could not find it explicitly stated in your question) you will be better off with EPSG:4326.

A trick you have to work around is the ggmap being labeled in EPSG:4326 (unprojected degrees) but actually drawn in EPSG:3857 (projected meters in Mercator) a possible approach is described over here [How to put a geom_sf produced map on top of a ggmap produced raster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749078/how-to-put-a-geom-sf-produced-map-on-top-of-a-ggmap-produced-raster)

Building upon the question linked I propose the following:

```
library(sf)
library(ggmap)

poly <- st_polygon(list(as.matrix(data.frame(lon = c(-62, -43, -43, -62, -62),
                                             lat = c(43, 43, 70, 70, 43))))) %>%
  st_sfc(crs = 4326) 

grid_box <- c(left   = -70, 
              right  = -30,
              bottom = 35,
              top    = 70)

base <- get_stamenmap(grid_box, zoom = 5, 
                      maptype = "terrain-background", 
                      color = "color")

ggmap_bbox <- function(map) {
  if (!inherits(map, "ggmap")) stop("map must be a ggmap object")
  # Extract the bounding box (in lat/lon) from the ggmap to a numeric vector, 
  # and set the names to what sf::st_bbox expects:
  map_bbox <- setNames(unlist(attr(map, "bb")), 
                       c("ymin", "xmin", "ymax", "xmax"))
  
  # Coonvert the bbox to an sf polygon, transform it to 3857, 
  # and convert back to a bbox (convoluted, but it works)
  bbox_3857 <- st_bbox(st_transform(st_as_sfc(st_bbox(map_bbox, crs = 4326)), 3857))
  
  # Overwrite the bbox of the ggmap object with the transformed coordinates 
  attr(map, "bb")$ll.lat <- bbox_3857["ymin"]
  attr(map, "bb")$ll.lon <- bbox_3857["xmin"]
  attr(map, "bb")$ur.lat <- bbox_3857["ymax"]
  attr(map, "bb")$ur.lon <- bbox_3857["xmax"]
  map
}

# Use the function:
base <- ggmap_bbox(base)

ggmap(base) +
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(3857)) +
  geom_sf(data = st_transform(poly, 3857), 
          col = "red", fill = NA,
          inherit.aes = F) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

[image: map of area of interest - red box on stamen map]

Comment: 1/2 Thanks @Jindra Lacko. Good point about the coordinates being in lat/lon rather than m.  I have updated my question to make this explicit.  Unfortunately, when I try the following I still end up with an error message:
poly <- st_polygon(list(as.matrix(data.frame(lon = c(-62, -43, -43, -62, -62),
                                             lat = c(43, 43, 70, 70, 43))))) %>%
  st_sfc(crs = 4326)
ggmap(base) +
  geom_sf(data = poly, 
          aes(geometry = geometry),
          col = "red")

Comment: 2/2 Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
Error in `geom_sf()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 4th layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'lon' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Thanks @Jindra Lacko.  Works perfectly and I really appreciate the time you took to explain all the steps in the function.

Comment: Glad you worked that out! The combination of degrees and Web Mercator is tricky indeed!

Answer (score 1):

Although already answered, I would like to share another approach for this issue. You can extract easily tiles with `maptiles` and plot that seamlessly with `tidyterra`. The only thing to bear in mind is that tiles are provided usually in EPSG:3857, so you may want to get and plot the tiles on that projection in order to be displayed with full detail. Otherwise the projection of a raster (that involves resampling) would create some deformations on the final images.

See:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(maptiles)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tidyterra'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter


poly <- st_polygon(list(as.matrix(data.frame(
  lon = c(-62, -43, -43, -62, -62),
  lat = c(43, 43, 70, 70, 43)
)))) %>%
  st_sfc(crs = 4326) 

# Grid to polygon 

grid_box <- c(-70, 35, -30, 70)
class(grid_box) <- "bbox"
grid_poly <- st_as_sfc(grid_box) %>% st_set_crs(4326) %>%
  st_transform(3857)
 

basemap <- get_tiles(grid_poly, provider = "Stamen.Terrain", crop = TRUE)


ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster_rgb(data = basemap) +
  geom_sf(data = poly, fill = NA, color = "red") +
  coord_sf(crs=3857, expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @dieghernan.  I don't think there can ever be too many solutions to these types of questions, so it's great to see this alternative.