# How to properly combine a polygon map on top of a raster map in r?

Tags: r, gis, r-sf, ggmap, stamen-maps

I would like to combine a shapefile map of some US states on top of a raster map obtained from using library `ggmap`.

This is the code I have

```
library(USAboundaries)
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

us.state.longlat <- us_states()
us.state.longlat.cropped.large <- sf::st_crop(us.state.longlat, 
                                              c(xmin=-100, xmax=-80, ymin=30, ymax=50))

bbox <- setNames(st_bbox(us.state.longlat.cropped.large), 
                 c("left", "bottom", "right", "top"))

ggmap(get_map(bbox, source = "stamen", zoom = 5)) +
  geom_sf(data = us.state.longlat.cropped.large,
          inherit.aes = FALSE,
          color = "red", 
          fill = "transparent")
```

This is what I got:

[image]

Also got the following warning that I am not sure what it means:

```
Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
```

As you see there is a mismatch between the US state shapefile and the raster map.
The coordinate reference system for the shapefile map `us.state.longlat.cropped.large` is this:

```
st_crs(us.state.longlat.cropped.large)
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: EPSG:4326 
  wkt:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],
        AREA["World."],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
```

The issue seems to be less worrisome when cropping a small area map. For example:

```
us.state.longlat.cropped.small <- sf::st_crop(us.state.longlat, c(xmin=-92, xmax=-85, ymin=32, ymax=36))
bbox <- setNames(st_bbox(us.state.longlat.cropped.small), 
                 c("left", "bottom", "right", "top"))

ggmap(get_map(bbox, source = "stamen", zoom = 7)) +
  geom_sf(data = us.state.longlat.cropped.small,
          inherit.aes = FALSE,
          color = "red", 
          fill = "transparent")
```

This is what I got for a reduced area of the map:
[image]

In any case, I don't know what I am missing here but in both cases state borders should match between the shapefile and the raster map.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put a geom\_sf produced map on top of a ggmap produced raster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749078/how-to-put-a-geom-sf-produced-map-on-top-of-a-ggmap-produced-raster)

Comment: Before plotting your sf object projection should match with raster's (epsg:3857), apparently coordinates in bbox of  `get_map()` result must be updated, check `ggmap_bbox()` function in the accepted answer of previously linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is due to different CRS on the tile (most likely EPSG:3857) and the shapefile (probably EPSG:4326).

I would recommend an approach with two newer packages:

- `maptiles` allows to download map tiles as true `SpatRaster` objects, so they can be modified accordingly.
- `tidyterra` (shameless plug since I am the developer) allows to plot `SpatRaster` objects on the `ggplot2` system. Also `tidyterra` is compatible with `ggplot2::coord_sf()`, meaning that the `SpatRaster` and the `sf` object would be internally projected to the same CRS thus avoding the inconsistencies your are facing with `ggmap`

An additional word of caution: **almost all** the WMTS services (tiles, as OSM, Stamen, GoogleMaps, etc) provides the tiles on EPSG:3857 (WebMercator). What `maptiles` does is returning the tile on the CRS of the object you provide. This means that if you provide an object on a CRS that is not EPSG:3857 (e.g. lonlat EPSG:4326 on your example) `maptiles` would reproject the raster. As reprojecting rasters is quite different than reprojection vectors (`sf`) the reprojected raster would look deformed.

See a reprex and also this related question: [setting CRS for plotting with stamenmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74733975/setting-crs-for-plotting-with-stamenmaps/74751521)

```r
library(USAboundaries)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)


us.state.longlat <- us_states()
us.state.longlat.cropped.large <- sf::st_crop(
  us.state.longlat,
  c(xmin = -100, xmax = -80, ymin = 30, ymax = 50)
)

# Since tiles are usually in EPSG:3857 this would avoid deformations
us.state.mercator.cropped.large <- st_transform(us.state.longlat.cropped.large, 3857)

library(maptiles)
library(tidyterra)

tile <- get_tiles(us.state.mercator.cropped.large, "Stamen.Terrain",
  zoom = 5,
  crop = TRUE
)

# Crop exactly to extent
tile_crop <- terra::crop(tile, us.state.mercator.cropped.large)

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster_rgb(data = tile_crop) +
  geom_sf(
    data = us.state.mercator.cropped.large,
    color = "red",
    fill = "transparent"
  ) +
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE)
```

[image]