# How to combine ggplot2 and autoplot.OpenStreetMap

Tags: r, ggplot2, openstreetmap, r-sf

I am having trouble displaying an osm map under a series of points.

The shapefile is contained within a dataframe (df).

when I run this code,

```
df <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude")) 
ggplot(df) + geom_sf() + theme_void()
```

I get this result:

[image: result 1]

and when I run this code,

```
dc <- openmap(c(19.353014580954277,-99.14118184937192), 
                    c(19.287683266903073,-99.03186392856783), 
                    zoom = NULL,
                    type = "osm", 
                    mergeTiles = TRUE)
autoplot.OpenStreetMap(dc) + theme_void()
```

I get this result:

[image: result 2]

I've tried multiple ways and read a lot of tutorials and cheat sheets and still don't understand how to combine these two to create one image,

Comment: My personal choice for this is maptiles + tidyterra for map tiles, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75214294/how-to-properly-combine-a-polygon-map-on-top-of-a-raster-map-in-r I think is easier

Comment: thanks for the reply, but that post is even more confusing and besides, I'm not working in the US so those US specific functions don't work for this :/

Comment: I added an answer on this. See how to switch from OpenStreetMap to maptiles + tidyterra. Note also that OpenStreetMap package has not been updated in the last 4 years, so it is not actively maintained and IMHO outdated.

Answer (score 1):

1. instead of `geom_sf()` I used `geom_point()`.
2. I also had to set the projection for the osm raster

```r
dc <- openmap(c(19.353014580954277,-99.14118184937192), 
                         c(19.287683266903073,-99.03186392856783), 
                         zoom = NULL,
                         type = "osm", 
                         mergeTiles = TRUE)
     
#2.4: plotear mapas
dc <- openproj(dc, projection = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

autoplot.OpenStreetMap(dc) + geom_point(data=df, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude)) + theme_void()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my comment, I do believe the approach with **maptiles** + **tidyterra** is easier for plotting basemaps. Note that you can retrieve also map tiles for OpenStreetMaps with **maptiles**, but you would get a SpatRaster (spatial raster) that is truly a geographic object.
Let's start by creating your `df` with mock data from OpenStreetMap using **nominatimlite** (you didn't provide this data on the example so I had to get some points in your study area):

```r
# Mock your df using restaurants on the bbox
thebbox <- c(
  -99.14118184937192, 19.353014580954277,
  -99.03186392856783, 19.287683266903073
)

library(nominatimlite)
df <- geo_amenity(thebbox,
  amenity = "restaurant", limit = 50,
  lat = "Latitude", lon = "Longitude"
)
```

Now we start to follow your code. One thing t note is that when you convert `df` to a `sf` object you should add the corresponding CRS to the object itself. As `Longitude/Latitude` are geographic coordinates, it is safe enough to consider
`crs = "+proj=lonlat"`:

```r
# Start here
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

df <- st_as_sf(df,
  coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"),
  # Add crs
  crs = "+proj=lonlat"
)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Good. Now, for getting base maps we can use **maptiles** with `provider = "OpenStreetMap"`.

**An important thing to bear in mind is** that map tiles services usually provides the images in Mercator projection (i.e. Google Maps, etc.). So you may want to retrieve and plot the base tiles in Mercator.

Using a different CRS would cause the tile to be resampled and the results would not be as clean as the ones you would get using Mercator:

```r
# Now use maptiles instead, with Mercator to get better results
df_merc <- st_transform(df, 3857)

library(maptiles)
dc <- get_tiles(df_merc, provider = "OpenStreetMap", zoom = 13)

#> Data and map tiles sources:
#> © OpenStreetMap contributors
```

Last step: Use **ggplot2** and **tidyterra** to plot the RGB tile. **tidyterra** add additional geoms to ggplot2 for ploting SpatRaster objects:

```r
# And finally plot with ggplot2 + tidyterra
library(tidyterra)

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster_rgb(data = dc) +
  geom_sf(data = df) +
  coord_sf(crs = 3857)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

And that's all. A short version of the code (assuming you already have `df`) is:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(maptiles)
library(tidyterra)

df <- st_as_sf(df,
  coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"),
  # Add crs
  crs = "+proj=lonlat"
)
df_merc <- st_transform(df, 3857)
dc <- get_tiles(df_merc, provider = "OpenStreetMap", zoom = 13)
ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster_rgb(data = dc) +
  geom_sf(data = df) +
  coord_sf(crs = 3857)
```